# Can I trigger ajax request in rails controller?

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm newby of rails. I want to change Web UI(text) whenever some data is changed.
I know that the general ajax request is triggered when a user does some action such as click.

However, I want to trigger ajax request without some action of user like click.
is it possible?

if it is impossible, i will use setTimeout of jquery.

if I use setTimeout of jquery for periodical update of Web UI, can I trigger setTimeout when the server is started?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as i saw your question, I remembered that I have used jquery within a controller in my earlier projects.
Look at the following snippet,

```
  def test_method
    @rent_roll
    if request.xhr?
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js {
          render :update do |page|
            page.replace_html  "container", :partial => "/lease/property_rentroll", :locals => {:rent_roll => @rent_roll}
            page << "jQuery('#lease_rent_roll).hide();"
          end
        }
      end
    end
  end
```

In the line, ***page << "jQuery('#lease_rent_roll).hide();"***, it means we can use jquery within a controller, Then why can't we use ajax calls within that block?

Try as follows:

```
page << "jQuery('#lease_rent_roll).hide(); jQuery.ajax({ });"
```

I have'nt tried this yet. But you do have a try and let me know if it works.

Thanks!!

Comment: I tried this, but there was request nil error. To use 'respond_to' method, the action has to receive a request. Is it right? If it is right, Can I make a ajax request in controller ?

Comment: Yes, before the ajax call gets triggered in the controller, you need to call the method "test_method" via Ajax call from anywhere in your application., then only the condition gets passed in through "request.xhr?" and responds to your call & proceed further.